# Assign a public IP address to new Amazon Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip, amazon-elastic-ip

My Amazon Instance got terminated accidentaly. This Instance was having an IP address associated with itself so that it can be accessed from internet.

Now I have created another Instance from the snapshot of the previous one and now I want to assign the same IP address to the current Instance so that I can mask the server failure at the front end.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto the AWS Console and goto Elastic IP. There you will see the IP Address that was previously attached to your ec2. Select the IP Address and Associate to new EC2 instance that you have launched.

If you have released the Elastic IP previously, then I believe you can't retrieve that Elastic IP.

Comment: -- It worked perfectly. I was able to attach the elastic ip. But am not able to access it from net. DoI have to make some other setting changes??

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say you are not able to access it from net. Which service are you running on this server ?  Please check to make sure your Security Group allows the service you are going to access from outside network.

Comment: Actually I forgot to open the ports. Did that and all working smoothly.